# Google maps mousewheel scrolling

Tags: usability-testing, maps

I was wondering if anyone would be able to advise on a debate my business partners and I are having... In the interest of fairness, I'm not going to say which side I am on, but I'd like to get some feedback from some pros. Below is a link to the site in question and we are split on whether or not to disable mousewheel scrolling on the map.

I'd really appreciate some feedback on which option you all think is most appropriate, and thanks in advance for any help you can give :)

https://www.vapetrotter.com/directory/

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty straight forward, If the scroll bar solves the user needs then you can retain the mouse scroll wheel. I see the purpose is to find the Vape store and make comment, rating, share and add photo..